# How to compile less to css into another directory using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, less

My directory `/public/less` contains all my less files.

How to configure node.js to compile those files to another directory? e.g `/public/compiled-stylesheets`

my default express configuration is:

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.compiler({ src:__dirname + '/public', enable:['less']}));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: use connect-asset might be a solution https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets, otherwise you can set a bash script with lessc and node server.js, run it as start server script.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you always just do a file copy / move when compilation is done?

https://gist.github.com/992478

Comment: It sounds like a workaround, isn't? By the way, the less plugin doesn't do that automatically, correct?